# Invalid use of repetition operators

Tags: r

I try to reproduce [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28892252) code for my case:

```
word_vec <- paste(c('bonkobuns ', 'exomunch ', 'calipodians ', 
          'relimited '), collapse="|")
 gsub(word_vec, '', df1$text)
```

However I receive this error:

```
Invalid use of repetition operators
```

The problem is with the following expressions:

```
c("c++", "c#", "vb.net", "objective-c")
```

How can I include them into the word list?

Comment: `+` and `.` are special characters in regex. You need to escape them with backslashes  `\\` if you want to use them in an expression. (Note you need 2 backslashes in R since you have to escape the backslash itself)

Comment: @divibisan how could I make the expression to use them?

Comment: @divibisan \ ++ ?

Comment: rather than escaping the special characters it'll probably be easier to use `gsub` with `fixed` parameter set to `TRUE`

Comment: It would be better if you included a reproducible example, the way you present the problem doesn't allow us to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I thought that too, but the OP is building a list with the pipe (`|`) and that needs to be executed as a regular expression.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I tried fixed equals to true. I don't have error but there is anything removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
wordVec <- c("c++", "c#", "vb.net", "objective-c")
```

You will need to escape special characters like `+` specifically from the error message, but also things like `.` to be safe. Here we add a slash infront of those characters while building the expression.

```
wordList <- paste(gsub("([+.])","\\\\\\1", wordVec), collapse="|")
cat(wordList) # to remove extra string escapes
# c\+\+|c#|vb\.net|objective-c
```

And we can test with

```
textVec <- paste("use the", wordVec, "tag")
# [1] "use the c++ tag"         "use the c# tag"         
# [3] "use the vb.net tag"      "use the objective-c tag"
gsub(wordList, "", textVec)
# [1] "use the  tag" "use the  tag" "use the  tag" "use the  tag"
```

Comment: you don't need to escape the special characters in the group, and `-` is not special, so it will work with just `([+.])`

Answer (score 2):

@MrFlick's solution is the most idiomatic and efficient solution. Nevertheless, if we want to make it work with `fixed= TRUE` we could use `Reduce` :

```
Reduce(function(x,y) gsub(y,"",x,fixed=TRUE), wordVec, textVec)

# [1] "use the  tag" "use the  tag" "use the  tag" "use the  tag"
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` and `.` are special characters in regex. The particular error you're getting is from the `++`: `+` means, match the preceding character 1 or more times. Trying to repeat a repeat character doesn't make sense, hence the error.

To match an actual `+` or `.` in regex, You need to escape them by putting backslashes `\\` in front of them. Note that you need 2 backslashes in R since you have to escape the backslash too.

Example:

`C++` should be written as `C\\+\\+` or `C\\+{2}`