# Keep word into a dataframe

Tags: r

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28891708/8831872) example answer

I try to use it to keep words into a whole column.

I use this:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c ("Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example"))
words <- c("this", "is", "an", "example")
paste(intersect(strsplit(df$text, "\\s")[[1]], words), collapse=" ")
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in strsplit(df$text, "\\s") : non-character argument
```

What can I do?

Comment: You need to wrap with `as.character` as tthe 'text' is `factor` (check the `str(df)`- or specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the dataset) i.e. `paste(intersect(strsplit(as.character(df$text), "\\s")[[1]], words), collapse=",")` Note that here are subsetting the 1st list element only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you want to apply the function for each text in your data frame, the following code should do what you need:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c ("Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example"))
words <- c("this", "is", "an", "example")

df$new_column <- sapply(as.character(df$text), function(x) {
  return(paste(intersect(strsplit(x, "\\s")[[1]], words), collapse=" "))
})

print(df$new_column)
```

And with a different data.frame example:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c ("Hi this is an example", "Hi this was an example", "Hi this still is an example", "Hi this is another example"))
words <- c("this", "is", "an", "example")

df$new_column <- sapply(as.character(df$text), function(x) {
  return(paste(intersect(strsplit(x, "\\s")[[1]], words), collapse=" "))
})

print(df$new_column)
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

df$text is a factor.  Try:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c ("Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example", "Hi this is an example"))
words <- c("this", "is", "an", "example")
paste(intersect(strsplit(as.character(df$text), "\\s")[[1]], words), collapse=" ")
```